# Which file to edit to show a certain message when connecting to ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I would like to make it so that whenever someone tries to connect to my server using SSH, it would show an ASCII art or some message, (Right when they're typing the user and password to connect)

Is there a specific file to edit for that?

Answer (score 2):

I just found out, it should be on /etc/sshd_config. To add a message just add the line

```
Banner /path/to_message
```

Comment: Also check that `PrintMotd` is not declared `no`

Answer (score 1):

The content of `/etc/motd` (Message of the day), is shown to anyone that logs-in to a text terminal via any means. So will work, but also for people logging in to the console.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it can be used this way as well!